# how to Set the position of Column in datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a problem i m making  a wpf application and using data grid Control to Show tabular data i m adding a Single Coloum in data Grid through Xaml And My All Other Column Would be add Dynamic my Fixed Column Comes At first postion in Grid i Want to be it  to be come At last

how can i achive it

my Xaml code is As below

Thanks in Advance
shashank`

```
            <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" Width="110" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="file:///D:\Projects\ChadCarpenter\AARFID\AARFID\Images\boardicon.png" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                   </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
                    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn> 
           </my:DataGrid.Columns>
```

> And below are my C #` 
>   public void CreateDataTableheader()
>           {

```
        if (Utility.CheckGroupFamily == "Group")
        {
            dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("Group Name", typeof(String));
        }
        dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(String));
        dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(String));
        dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(String));
        dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("CellPhone", typeof(String));
        dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("TowerID", typeof(String));
        dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("Room #", typeof(String));
        dtAdultinfo.Columns.Add("IS primary", typeof(int));

        Lst.ItemsSource = dtAdultinfo.DefaultView;

        //DataGridColumn dc;
        //DataGridTemplateColumn  dgColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

        //DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();

        //dgColumn.Header="Edit";
        //dgColumn.Width = 110;
        //dgColumn.IsReadOnly= true;


        //dgColumn.CellTemplate = dt;
        //Image img = new Image();
        //BitmapImage logo=new BitmapImage();

        //logo.UriSource =new Uri("file:///D:/Projects/ChadCarpenter/AARFID/AARFID/Images/boardicon.png");


        DataGridTemplateColumn dgColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        dgColumn.Header = "Edit";
        FrameworkElementFactory factory1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
        Binding b1 = new Binding("Picture");
        b1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        factory1.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, b1);
        DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
        cellTemplate1.VisualTree = factory1;
        dgColumn.CellTemplate = cellTemplate1;
        Lst.Columns.Add(dgColumn);`
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create the dynamic columns.

Comment: i m also try to Add my Fixed Column through Code behind.. but it Also Doesn't Work

Comment: May i know which version of .Net you are using and the Visual Studio Version?

Answer (score 5):

It might be late but in order to help others in similar issues, setting `DatagridColumn.DisplayIndex` in `AutoGeneratedColumns` event will do the trick.

Assuming Column with `Header = "Edit"` is your fixed column and your `DataGrid` looks like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <... />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn> 
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then you can find the desired column by it's header and send it to the last position:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGrid)sender;
    foreach (var item in grid.Columns)
    {
        if (item.Header.ToString() == "Edit")
        {
            item.DisplayIndex = grid.Columns.Count - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```